# Reported versions of the sentences like "If I wanted to go, I would go"

Tags: grammar, usage, conditional-constructions, reported-speech

I am having trouble in terms of the reported versions of the sentences which include the word "if". Can you please tell me what the reported versions of these "direct speech" kind of sentences below are?

> 1) He said/thought(etc.), "If I wanted to go, I would go"
>
> 2) He said/thought(etc.), "I would go if I wanted to go"
>
> 3) He said/thought(etc.), "If I had wanted to go, I would have gone"
>
> 4) He said/thought(etc.), "I would have gone if I had wanted to go"
>
> 5) He said/thought(etc.), "If somebody touches me without asking, I feel so angry"
>
> 6) He said/thought(etc.), "I feel so angry if somebody touches me without asking"

By "reported version", I mean the sentences like **"He said (that) he feels so angry if somebody touches him without asking".** For example when I report the the quote in the 6th sentence, I am not sure if I should say **"He said (that) he feels so angry if somebody touches him without asking"** or **"He said (that) he felt so angry if somebody touched him without asking"** or if I can say either of them (in the sentences which don't include the word "if", we can report it either way). I would like you to help me.

Comment: They are all correct. Although, in the last two sentences anyway, I would replace *if* with *when*. (*He said that he feels angry when somebody touches him without asking.*) But the verb tense is up to you. It depends on whether or not it's a past action that has since stopped (**felt**), or something that is ongoing (**feels**).

Comment: The Present Tense construction *If somebody **does** X, I do Y* strongly implies that this action/reaction has happened many times before, but the "Past Tense" version *If somebody **did** X, I **would** do Y* refers to a ***hypothetical*** situation (which may never have happened before).

Comment: @Jason Bassford Thank you for the answer, but the sentences I gave are direct speech kind of sentences, and I am asking what their indirect versions are.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. I know, but shouldn't it be backshifted after "said"?

Comment: We don't *have* to "backshift" reported speech (there's nothing wrong with *He said his name is John*, for example). So in the case of your example #6 we probably wouldn't (because that would be likely to alter the implied nuance of meaning).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah. I asked a wrong question. Yes, as I said in the OP, I know that we don't have to backshift it there. But why would it probably change the implied meaning? Backshifting normally doesn't change the meaning.

Comment: Compare 1) *He said he **feels** so angry if somebody **touches** him without asking* and 2) *He said he **felt** so angry if somebody **touched** him without asking*. You could reasonably follow #1 there with *So be sure to ask before you touch him*, and you could follow #2 with *Since talking it through with his psychiatrist, though, he doesn't have that problem any more*. But it would be nonsensical to reverse those two follow-ons. Does that clarify the difference to you?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok. I know that it would be nonsensical to reverse them.But would it also be wrong to say **"He said he felt so angry if somebody touched him without asking. So be sure to ask him before you touch him."**? Is it wrong to use the backshift version for talking about how he feels about being touched now?

Comment: @DereMemo Yes, I know. I was commenting on the the indirect versions that you gave in the paragraph after your quotes. (Which is also why I gave an example of indirect speech.)

Comment: I don't understand. I just told you that *reversing* those two follow-ons would be nonsensical, *and you agreed*. But now you seem to be asking whether it's "wrong" to do this (using the example *He said he felt so angry if somebody touched him without asking. So be sure to ask him before you touch him*). The reason native speakers would use ***feels + touches*** there is because this is *an ongoing feature* of how he reacts - and the context makes it clear it's *relevant to time of utterance* (the time of reporting what he said, not the time when he originally said it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers What I don't understand is, we normally can backshift. Why is it wrong to backshift when we use the word "if"? Normally we can say either "He told me he was ok" or "he told me he is ok" and they both mean the same exact thing.

Comment: @DereMemo: It's nothing to do with ***if***. We often backshift reported speech simply because both the act of saying something *and* the thing said are now in the past.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am sorry. I don't agree with you. The backshifted version and the non-backshifted version completely have the same meanings.

Comment: @DereMemo: Suit yourself. I thought I'd clearly explained (in my comment starting *Compare...)* that backshifting *can* affect possible meanings. But if you think you know better, it's not my job to *persuade* you.